# Unable to install Ubuntu, ACPI Errors

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd, acpi

I have a Asus Rog Strix G18 Laptop (2023) with a 4090 RTX.
I installed two SSD SN850X 4TB then I installed Windows 11 and wanted to install Ubuntu (dual boot).
The installation process go smoothly (only for Ubuntu 22, I tried 20 and 23 but neither detected my SSDs).
When I restart my computer after choosing to start Ubuntu in GRUB I get the following output:

```
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.SS08._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - \_SB_.PC00.LPCB.SEN2 (20221020/dspkginit-438)
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (193000a1)
```

The first 2 messages are actually repeated a few times.
Any idea how to fix this?

Cheers

Comment: Asus is not officially supporting Linux. New devices need usually some time, till somebody reverse engineered the device to make everything run.

Comment: I would be more worried about "nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (193000a1)",  The ACPI errors we ALL have and are benign.

Comment: @Rinzwind it could be because my GPU is the RTX4090 which is recent, so it might not have drivers available in Linux yet?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my issue, I started Ubuntu in recovery mode, updated all the packages, then I installed cuda with the following commands:

**wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin

sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2204.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600

wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.2.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local_12.2.0-535.54.03-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local_12.2.0-535.54.03-1_amd64.deb

sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install cuda**